# Cross compile shared library for armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi Rust [Mindstorm Ev3dev]

Tags: linux, rust, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Parameters:

- source = x86_x64 windows 10 or x86_x64 linux (ubuntu wsl)
- target = armv5te linux
- target_type = cdylib
- target_glibc = 2.24
- language = rust
- build_tool = cargo
- compiler = rustc

(The target is a Lego Mindstorm running a linux image from [Ev3dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/))

Cargo Configuration:

```
[package]
name = "ev3"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
jni = "0.19"
ev3dev-lang-rust = { version = "0.12.1", features=["screen"]}
jni_proc_macro= {path= "./jni_proc_macro"}

[lib]
crate-type= ["cdylib"]

[workspace]
members= ["jni_proc_macro"]
```

Build Configuration:

```
[build]
target = "armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi"

[target.armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi]
linker = "rust-lld"
```

Build Error:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: {...}
= note:   rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc_s
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lutil
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lrt
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lpthread
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lm
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -ldl
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lc


error: could not compile `ev3` due to previous error
```

As the error suggests the linker is missing libraries. I found no clear solution where I can download and or provide these dependencies.

My question is, A is there a diffrent way to build this successfully or B how do I solve these dependencies.

The result needs to be a shared library (.so) for linux and armv5te

Comment: Have you set up the target platform tool chain? If not, have you looked into  [Cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross)?

Comment: I just briefly glanced over the cross md. They say they support my target. It seems like I will need to setup docker first. For your first question: I installed the toolchain using rustup target add ... Both the musl and the gnu version. Both compile staticlib successfully. Musl doesn't support dynamic libs and gnu gives me the error above.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to set up docker; but it might be easier as setting up the toolchain manually can be a pain in the butt depending on your platform. It's not just as easy as `rustup install <triplet>`, you still need a armv5te-unknown-linux linker, and armv5te-unknown-linux libs, and you'd need to point to them correctly (which cross containerization makes easy, you pretty much get a vm of your target machine with all those bits and bobs installed and configured). Musl also should support dynamic libs, it's just a different libc linked statically by default, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I will try docker then. I thought that it couldn't be that difficult to find a the linker and b the libs for a platform. But I can't really find anything. Musl not supporting dynamic libs is a implementation problem. It is written on a rust site about toolchains that "some toolchains are hard coded for static linking" and armv5te musl is one of them. Either way gnu static linking works too so I assume that even if musl would support dynamic libs I would have the same problem.

Comment: What I'm saying is musl is statically linked, ***but that's only the libc that is statically linked***. All of the musl targets statically link their libc, the gnu targets dynamically link their libc. You can link any other native dynamic C libs that your code might depend on, such as openssl in a musl target.

Comment: I used cross with docker and it was way to simple. @MeetTitan thank you very much for the help. Do you like to post it as an answer or I will write an answer crediting you myself.

Comment: You should write the answer; document the steps you took and what worked for you. It'll help someone on a Google search, and I'll give ya an uptick

Comment: I faced another issue. The docker image of cross has glibc 2.28 and requires it when using the dynamic library. My target only supports 2.24. I have no idea how to alter the docker image if possible to use glibc 2.24 instead.

Comment: I would use a musl target in that instance and not worry about glibc

Comment: Like I mentioned above rust armv5te linux musl does not support so as a target. Otherwise I would 100%agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Requirements

- wsl or linux installed
- cargo and rustc installed

(everthing is done in wsl/linux)

### Prep/Build

Install cross on cargo

```
cargo install cross --git https://github.com/cross-rs/cross
```

Install docker
Clone the cross repository
Navigate into the docker folder
Create a new file with the name "Dockerfile.armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cross"
Paste this in the new file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

COPY common.sh lib.sh /
RUN /common.sh

COPY cmake.sh /
RUN /cmake.sh

COPY xargo.sh /
RUN /xargo.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
    g++-arm-linux-gnueabi \
    crossbuild-essential-armel \
    libc6-dev-armel-cross

COPY deny-debian-packages.sh /
RUN TARGET_ARCH=armel /deny-debian-packages.sh \
    binutils \
    binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi

# Qemu is disabled since we've changed the scripts to require newer Python versions.
#COPY qemu.sh /
#RUN /qemu.sh arm

COPY qemu-runner base-runner.sh /

ENV CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabi-
ENV CROSS_SYSROOT=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
ENV CARGO_TARGET_ARMV5TE_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABI_LINKER="$CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX"gcc \
    CARGO_TARGET_ARMV5TE_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABI_RUNNER="/qemu-runner arm" \
    AR_armv5te_unknown_linux_gnueabi="$CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX"ar \
    CC_armv5te_unknown_linux_gnueabi="$CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX"gcc \
    CXX_armv5te_unknown_linux_gnueabi="$CROSS_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX"g++ \
    BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS_armv5te_unknown_linux_gnueabi="--sysroot=$CROSS_SYSROOT" \
    QEMU_LD_PREFIX="$CROSS_SYSROOT" \
    RUST_TEST_THREADS=1 \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/pkgconfig/:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
```

Make sure the project uses "LF" newlines. if not [this](https://superuser.com/questions/757081/how-do-i-convert-all-files-in-a-folder-to-a-different-line-ending-on-windows) fixes it.
Compile the custom cross/docker build using the following command in the root of the cloned repository:

```
cargo build-docker-image armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cross
```

This will create a new docker image that will be used to compile the rust code.
Then navigate to your target project folder and run:

```
export CROSS_TARGET_ARMV5TE_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABI_IMAGE=ghcr.io/cross-rs/armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cross:local
```

(Do not close this terminal)
Now add the following to the Cargo.toml file:

```
[package.metadata.cross.build]
default-target = "armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi"
```

now you can run:

```
cross build
```

Many cargo options like "--release" can be used (for more info have a look at cross in the credits)

### Credits

- [MeetTitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4307644/meettitan)(Stackoverflow) who recomended me to use cross
- [Cross project](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross)(GitHub) which powers the whole solution
- [Custom cross version discussion](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross/discussions/1152)(Cross Github)
- [Alexhuszagh](https://github.com/Alexhuszagh)(Cross Github) who showed me how to build a custom cross version
- [Emilgardis](https://github.com/Emilgardis)(Cross Github) who explained the newline bug

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out! I didn't think it would require a custom docker container, but now you know how to cross compile almost anything